# Two USB ports for one IC

Tags: power, usb, data

I have to get two USB 2.0 ports connected to a single chip delivering data and power. If only one port is connected, this connection and power should be forwarded to the IC and if both are connected the second port must be completely shut down.

Can you help me out with that?

Comment: why do you need two ports if one of them must be disabled? .... how would you determine which port is the "second port"?

Comment: Our customer wants two input ports because of different connector types (mini b and micro b). Sometimes both ports are connected to different PCs, then the micro b port should be used.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a mux to switch between the two data lanes. You could, for example, use an [FSUSB42](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FSUSB42-D.PDF) with the respective \$V_\mathrm{BUS}\$ for the `Sel` line. Power switching may be a little trickier, but hard to say without knowing what you have downstream from the USB ports.

Bear in mind, this will cause problems when the user plugs in the "master" USB while the other port is in the middle of a transaction. This sounds like a very bad design choice, and it would be much better to actually have a physical switch to control both the mux `Sel` line and the power supply.

Comment: Any switching controlled by mechanical connection would be a very bad design choice, including physical switch. The data switching should be a software decision, _guided_ (not forced) by sensing connect/disconnect events, IMHO

Comment: @Maple I totally agree, this shouldn't be left to a user - simply a plaster on a bad design..! The hope would be that the user would safely switch of one before switching, but we know that wouldn't be the case :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need High Speed, your best bet is likely to be two EZ-USB FX2, each handling one port, and one of the chips being able to send the other into suspend mode (or a proper protocol with gracious shutdown instead of generating a surprise eject event).

Comment: Agreed, this sounds like the most sensible approach. Note, however, that the EZ-USB FX2 (CY7C68013) is obsolete and should not be used in new designs. The replacement is the EZ-USB FX2**LP** (CY7C68013A).